# Can I make use of my Global Entry card to get Pre-Check if my airline doesn't participate?

Tags: global-entry, tsa-precheck

I will be flying on All Nippon Airways (ANA) out of Houston IAH soon, but ANA does not participate in the Trusted Traveler program so I have no way to provide the KTN that I received through Global Entry. Is there any way that I can access the Pre-Check lane in IAH using my Global Entry card (my ticket will not say Pre-check) or am I out of luck?

Edit: I believe this question is distinct from 'can I use pre-check on non-pre airlines. There is no way to prove that you have pre-check, but I have a physical Global Entry card which I can use as legal identification to board an airplane, so in my mind it is more objective proof of my pre-cleared status.

Comment: :( Sorry, no.  Merely having a GE card doesn't get you Pre Check and there's no way to get a UA BP unless you actually have a UA flight.

Comment: You could do something nutty like book a fully refundable flight on another airline that does participate, go through security, and then cancel it, but I can't imagine how that would be worth your time.

Comment: ...just make sure that the patsy airline allows you to cancel the ticket after check-in (which is necessary to get a boarding pass).  Read the fare rules carefully.

Comment: I would not recommend booking a flight on the patsy airline as it is illogical to have two tickets on the same time period to two different locations.  Some Homeland Security scan will turn this up and have you pulled aside for questioning.  They are better organized than one might think.

Comment: @MichaelPotter However, "It's worth it to allow me to use pre-check" is a pretty good answer.

Comment: @MichaelPotter I recently went through pre-√ with a pair of conflicting flights and had no problem. First, I don't believe that DHS/TSA would even check for conflicts, and second, I don't think they'd care because there are legitimate reasons for it, and I don't see how it would be used to circumvent security anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your airline needs to participate in TSA Pre, and the Pre logo has to appear on your boarding pass to indicate your eligibility, so ... unfortunately, no.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think so but I wanted to find out for certain. I wish Japanese airlines would get on the ball and connect with the TSA.

Comment: The last I checked, the only foreign airlines that did TSA Pre were Air Canada and WestJet, both from Canada, although it's well possible other foreign airlines have signed up since.  These two were the logical first ones, as their US flight operations dwarf the rest of the non-U.S. world's flights.  (Fun fact: WestJet is the world's #1 foreign airline operator in Las Vegas.)

Answer (score 1):

You can join clear https://www.clearme.com/home.  Then you can go to the front of the regular security line.  You will still need to take off your shoes and remove your laptop from the bag, but at least you will not have to wait in line.  I use it and it works great.

Although this does not answer the question directly, this solves the OP's problem of getting thru security quickly.  Clear is available at IAH.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment, as it doesn't really answer the question. Clear isn't for everyone; it's only available in about 20 cities and is considerably more expensive than either Global Entry or TSA Precheck.